# What kind of combat situation warrants the use of frequency modulating phaser?

Tags: technology, weapons, combat, lasers

I'm comparing 2 modes of modulation: amplitude(AM) and frequency(FM). My understanding is if the phaser is set to stun I can lower the power which is exactly what AM phaser is preferred but what about FM phaser? Suppose my phaser can only contain 1 crystal, an energy source if you will so there are many expendable cartridges each contain different types of crystals. Some are more powerful than the other then why do I need FM(seems to me like manual calibration) which are both tedious and time consuming, I wonder what kind of situation would makes a FM phaser stands out?

Comment: you tagged lasers but your question is about phasers, which are only fictional weapons. You may need to provide more information about what "Amplitude" and "Frequency" modulation means in your universe. But I can say that fundamentally, if you need pulses at a single frequency, you use AM. If you need to hit with a broad range of frequencies (to get through shielding, for example), then FM will be harder to stop.

Comment: Amplitude and frequency modulation are for communication. And lowering power is just as easy to do in both forms of modulation.

Comment: In Star Trek canon, modulating the frequency of a phaser is needed to get through Borg shielding, which adapts to block single-frequency phaser fire. It also blocks the modulated phasers, but takes slightly longer. So the real answer is that FM is generally irrelevant. If you are close enough to fire a phaser, you are likely to be assimilated anyway.

Comment: If you are asking specifically about Star Trek, that is a different Stack Exchange.  If you are not, then you need to provide more details about these 'phasers'.

Answer (score 1):

## To get through energy shields

There is an arms race between shield technology and weapons technology. By modulating the frequency of the phasers, they may be able to penetrate certain types of shields.

This could be useful for both shooting out through your own shields without lowering them, or to increase your chances of penetrating an enemies shields.

Eg: https://gwvf.fandom.com/wiki/Kiron_Theory